# Excel VBA for opening a file with a date in the filename that changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that is created every day, named `"three day outlook 7-7-2014`. The date changes every day, but the files are stored by day in a folder, so I have multiple files named `"three day outlook"` but with different dates.

I am trying to use VBA code to open certain files by date that are selected by a date selection on another Excel sheet. I have tried the following:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=("C:\Users\sdfe\Documents\three day outlook" & Cells(D3).xlsx)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\sdfe\Documents\three day outlook " & Range("D3") & ".xlsx"
```

According to your question, there's a space character between the word "outlook" and the date. I assume the date is formatted on the sheet with the correct format. In fact, it might be better to show a message box with the path to the file you're trying to open. Something like:

```
MsgBox """C:\Users\sdfe\Documents\three day outlook " & Range("D3") & ".xlsx"""
```

and make sure this string is properly constructed before you use it.

**Update** (following your comment below):

Since your date is formatted as "7/7/2014" and not as "7-7-2014", there's a couple of things you can do:

1. Format the cell where the date is (D3) as **Text**, so that it gets entered as you like and doesn't change by the date formatting.
2. Format the cell where the date is (D3) with a **Custom** format of **`d-m-yyyy`** and then above, instead of `Range("D3")` use `Range("D3").Text`.
3. Keep the cell formatting as **Date** (as I assume it is), and then above, instead of `Range("D3")` use `Format(Range("D3"), "d-m-yyyy")`.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response.

Comment: Dijikay you are correct the path name is using a date range of 7/7/2014 instead of 7-7-2014. I have changed the format in excel and no luck. Do i need to change something in vba?

Comment: @user3146807: Now that you are happy with the result, please consider checking the tick mark on the left to accept the answer and let others know this was a useful and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the format function so that you always know what the date will appear like.  Everyone will have a different date format set on their computer.  And you never know if the computer just sends the date as just a number instead of a date.